# displaying jSON data another way from getJSON?

Tags: json

I am currently building a web application which allows users to favorite posts. I have a test jSON file with some data for testing purposes.

I had originally planned to store this long jSON string in the database, and pull from there to allow each user to have their own stored 'favorites' section.

I was able to store this jSON string in the database per user, but pulling that jSON data has been quite an issue.

I am able to pull jSON data from a file using `jQuery.getJSON("url")` but doing it this way would involve having a custom favorites file for each user. It is also a little more difficult to update and store a new file each time the user 'favorites' something.

Is there a way I can pull the jSON data from the database as a string and display it the same way I can with .getJSON, instead of having to call it in as a file??

sorry if this is unclear, I am new to JSON. I'm not sure what code I should provide, that's why I haven't.

Comment: getJSON is just loading content from a URL and interpreting it as JSON. Why is it that "pulling the JSON data has been quite an issue"? What issue are you having?

Comment: I was trying to pass the string into getJSON, sort of like this:

`$jsonFavoriteString = <?php echo $current_user->json_favorites; ?>

jQuery.getJSON( '<?php $jsonFavoriteString ?>, function(data) {
   // loop here
}`

but as you stated getJSON pulls in a file, not parse a string.

I know of parseJSON, but how would I run it through a loop to display all of the information in that object as I did with getJSON?

Comment: You're missing the point. getJSON does what you need it to do. It loads text from a file, and parses it into JSON. All you need to do is hook up your back-end to serve the correct JSON to your AJAX script. But it looks like you are trying to use getJSON as parseJSON because you already have your JSON string loaded from the server.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. My jSON code lies in the database under each specific user in the options table, and not in its own file. So I can't use getJSON because there is no file to point it to.

I have my jSON string (ive tested it with console.log), and I want to run a loop to display that information to the user. I have the loop set up and displaying correctly when I pull in that jSON data from a file. I am just confused I guess.  It is mostly my lack of knowledge on this subject as to why I am having issues really explaining my problem thoroughly.

Comment: By creating a URL/file to access for each user, you would be doing the same thing you are doing now. You don't need AJAX here. But your posted code has severe syntax errors and seems to be mixing PHP and JavaScript incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool to access the database and return the data to you in the correct format.

Since it looks like you've already started coding your front end in Javascript, it might be a good idea to look into coding the backend using [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/).

Another option (which might be simpler for your case) is to use something like [Elastic Search](http://elasticsearch.org/) which would allow you to store JSON documents and query them via [web api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html).

Comment: I'm building this up in wordpress, but left that bit of information out as to not confuse anyone. I can pull the string from the database based on the user, but I just can not figure out a way to parse and display the information. I can only do so with getJSON